# searching by property's value of geoJSON in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, geojson, openlayers-2

I have a map with 4 layers with the same attributes (not even the same values). an example of geoJSON is below:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": { "CODIF": "PBA177432V1", "Position_X": 397632.884, "Position_Y": 419958.3456, "Point_Kilo": 177000, "Type": "2CmPt", "Voie": "V1", "dist_rail": 2.75, "Status": "PBA 3.50m" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -6.511578939607725, 34.374296518950914 ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": { "CODIF": "PBA177437V1", "Position_X": 397633.7158, "Position_Y": 419952.8751, "Point_Kilo": 177000, "Type": "STM.TT (PA)", "Voie": "V1", "dist_rail": 2.75, "Status": "PBA 3.50m" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -6.51156926129586, 34.37424727692602 ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 2, "properties": { "CODIF": "PBA177457V1", "Position_X": 397636.6028, "Position_Y": 419933.597, "Point_Kilo": 177000, "Type": "STM.TT (PA)", "Voie": "V1", "dist_rail": 2.75, "Status": "PBA 3.50m" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -6.511535636308449, 34.374073743241354 ] } } 
]
}
```

I want to add a function that searches by value of property. ("CODIF" in this case). It means that when a user enters a value of property "CODIF" of a feature, he sees this feature.
I've added a function that searches by longitude and latitude values, but it has no relation with geoJSON properties (even if there are longitude and latitude properties in geoJSON file), as shown below:

```
$('#envoyer').click(function() {
    var lat = latitude.val();
    var long = longitude.val();

    if(long != '' && lat != '') {
        vectorSource.clear();
        vectorSource.addFeature(
            new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point([parseFloat(long), parseFloat(lat)]).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
            })
        );

        wkt.val('POINT(' + long + ' ' + lat + ')');
        map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize());
    }
    return false;
});
```

It responds to my need without being related to geoJSON properties values, and it's because of the nature of longitude and latitude properties, but for searching by "CODIF" property values, I must relate the function to geoJSON properties.

The HTML code of the function i should add is:

```
<div id="search">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search PKs by CODIF">
  <button type="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

I started my function with something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#search button', function() {
  var value = $('#search input').val();
```

What i need is to do a comparison of what a user entered as a value, with the values of "CODIF" property of geoJSON file, if it's found, the user will see the feature of this CODIF's value, and if not, he reads a message like: Not found.

Comment: Someone to help me please so i can continue my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to search for a feature based on a properties you can loop through your vector source and verify each feature's property "CODEIF" with the one desired like this:

```
yourVectorSource.forEachFeature( function(feature){
    if (feature.get('CODEIF')==yourDesiredValue){
        // add it on a temporary layer
        // and display it
        // while hiding yourVectorLayer
    }
});
```